# Solution of system congruences (proof)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have some troubles with the proof of the chinese remainder theorem to solve a system of linear congruences.

First of all, they are going to construct a general solution $x=a_1M_1y_1+...+a_nM_ny_n$, why is this always a solution for the system of congruences?

Next, they say that if $m_k$ divides $(x_0-x_1)$ then $M$ also divides $(x_0-x_1)$. Why is this true?

I uploaded the whole proof below:

[image]
 [image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by Theorem $4.9$ does not exist?

Comment: What is Theorem 4.9 saying? You need that if $m_i\mid X$, for $i=1,...,k$, then also $m_1\cdots m_k\mid X$ for pairwise coprime $m_i$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Why is that true? 4 divides 4 but 4*2 does not divide 4?

Comment: So you see, it follows from Theorem $4.9$: We have $x_0\equiv x_1\bmod m_i$ for $i=1,...,k$. To your comment before: $4$ and $2$ are **not** coprime.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thnx, Clear! How do they know $x=a_1M_1y_1+...+a_nM_ny_n$ is a solution of the system?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of you question, consider a particular $M_i$. If $j\neq i$ then $m_j | M_i$  thus  $$M_i\equiv 0\pmod{m_j}.$$
That is, adding any multiple of $M_i$ to an expression doesn't change its value $\pmod{m_j}$ as long as $i\neq j$. So we can drop all of the terms but one to see that $x\equiv a_j M_j y_j \pmod{m_j}$. Now we have chosen $y_j$ to be the multiplicative inverse of $M_j$, by construction, so that $x\equiv a_j M_j y_j \equiv a_j \pmod{m_j}$.

It appears that the second part of your question was addressed in the comments.